# Getting strange System.Drawing.Bitmap cannot be located error

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have both VS 2008 and VS 2010 installed on my Win7 box. But for sometime I'm getting this strange error:

`Type System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a cannot be located.`

I'm not able to put any buttons on toolstrips or modify many other properties of normal controls (like textboxes).

I have googled for it but different people got error for different reasons and none resolved my problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out at last. Don't know if this was entirely my mistake or there is something else also to this. It happened that I created a project in VS2008 and added some resource images to it, then I upgraded it to VS2010 and added some resource images to it. Now when I again reverted back to VS2008 it started facing the problem of `Type cannot be located error`.

To resolve I had to open the resource file and delete all the missing (or with error) resource images and re-add them (in VS2008).

Answer (score 0):

@TheVillageIdiot, deleting resources from the project will also delete the code lines the assign these resources to some controls properties, for example the code :

```
button.image = Resources.add_24x24;
```

will be deleted from the designer.cs file if you delete the "add_24x24" image, to not let that happen instead of deleting resources do the following: r-click on the Resources.resx file in the solution explorer and select open with and then select the XML Editor, replace the "version=4.0.0.0" with "version=2.0.0.0" for all resources with error, and it should work, that was if you moving project from vs 10 to vs 08, if vise do it vise versa.